# paperclip problem when re-generating thumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to re-create all thumbs. I'm not sure why is saying the key does not exist. I have AWS-S3 configured properly and it's working well (I can upload pictures with no problems.)

```
>> Attachment.all.each {|x|x.attachment.reprocess!}
AWS::S3::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
    /app/d999782b-a789-4763-ac86-e8c65fa781eb/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-    0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/error.rb:38:in `raise'
/app/d999782b-a789-4763-ac86-e8c65fa781eb/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:72:in `request'
/app/d999782b-a789-4763-ac86-e8c65fa781eb/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `get'
/app/d999782b-a789-4763-ac86-e8c65fa781eb/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:134:in `value'
```

When I tried to do the same to a single object seems to do it well, so the problem seems to be related to generating with a collection.

```
>> Attachment.last.attachment.reprocess!
=> true
```

UPDATE: I'm pretty sure it's related to the fact that there are uploaded files such as .htm that should be valid image files. Any idea how to skip them?

Comment: try to add some log information , Attachment.all.each {|x| Rails.logger.error "I'm processing #{x.id}" ; x.attachment.reprocess!}.or simple use puts in console. maybe a missing asset .

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and have not been able to figure it out either...

Comment: Martin -- Harald's answer solved it for me, you should give it a try and award him the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @Martin.. please accept an answer so that other users give a try to that one.. instead of trying out all the possibilities :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though I am not sure, but I hope this might help you.

```
Attachment.all.each { |x| x.attachment.reprocess! if ['.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.gif'].include?(File.extname(file_name))}
```

where `file_name => Name of the uploaded file`

Best of Luck

Answer (score 7):

Not sure where you've put your key for the AWS-S3, but you may have to specify that you want to run this under the production environment.

```
heroku rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Attachment RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Hey, interesting. That seems to fix it for me :) +50, thanks for answering this old question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your validations are set up but is it possible that some attachment objects can have a blank attachment? If so, try:

```
Attachment.all.each { |x| x.attachment.reprocess! rescue nil }
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It shows all the returned objects but It doesn't rebuild thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also refer to when an object(key) no longer exists on S3 but you have a record pointing to it in your database. This only happens if someone has made changes to the S3 bucket that don't mesh with what you have in your DB.

If that's the case you can use the ".exists?" method on the attachment to check if that key exists on Amazon's server's first, not that this will issue a read request.

This would change your reprocess command to something like this:

`Attachment.all.each { |x| x.attachment.reprocess! if x.attachment.exists? }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using:

```
rake paperclip:refresh
```

Instead?

Comment: Yes. "heroku rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Attachment" doesn't work. It says "The specified key does not exist."